# Вопрос по созданию диаграмм в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, er-diagram

Вот я щёлкаю по нужной папке правой мышой, выбираю в контекстном меню: *Diagrams*  → *Show Diagram...*  → *Java Class Diagrams* и появляется картинка, где представлены все классы. Перетаскиваю их с места на место, расставляя так как надо, сохраняю файл... И вот тут проблема:  сохранённом файле классы изображены вовсе не на тех местах, где были в момент сохранения. Как исправить это?